# How can I find the frequency of words in a list of Strings using Counter?

Tags: python-3.x

Example

```
text = [
     'this is the first document',
     'this document is the second document',
     'and this is the third one',
     'is this the first document?',
      ]
```

Expected Output

```
 { 'this' : 4 , 
   'is' : 4, 
   'the':4, .....etc}
```

I've tried to use this code but I'm getting word frequency for each sentence rather than for the entire list.

```
a = dict(Counter(text.split()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extract all the words in the sentences and construct a single list and pass that list to `Counter`. The code below should work:

```
words_in_all_sentences = [sentence.split(' ') for sentence in text]
all_words = [word for words_in_a_sentence in words_in_all_sentences for word in 
words_in_a_sentence]

print(Counter(all_words))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

text = [
     'this is the first document',
     'this document is the second document',
     'and this is the third one',
     'is this the first document?',
      ]

#chain.from_iterable --> to flatten the list
print(Counter(chain.from_iterable([i.split() for i in text])))  #str.split to split by space.
```

**Output:**

```
Counter({'this': 4,
         'is': 4,
         'the': 4,
         'document': 3,
         'first': 2,
         'second': 1,
         'and': 1,
         'third': 1,
         'one': 1,
         'document?': 1})
```